# Building a query param dynamically

Tags: coldfusion

Hi I am trying to build a query parameter dynamically, and am getting an error, i am using the code below,

```
<cfset featQuery="">
<cfloop list="#arguments.uid_features#" index="x">
<cfif x neq "0">
<cfif Len(featQuery) gt 0>
<cfset featQuery = featQuery& " AND ">
</cfif>
<cfset featQuery = featQuery & 'uid_prodf_featid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="' & x & '">'>
</cfif>
</cfloop>
```

I get this error message from coldfusion;
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '<'.

If i look at the output, it looks correct, but normaly using cfquerypram, you just get (param1), uid_prodf_featid=(param1) in the error message it displays the following;

```
uid_prodf_featid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="5">
```

Jason

Comment: What version of CF are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really build and execute CFML dynamically like you're attempting to do.  It looks to me like you're trying to build a SQL query outside of a cfquery tag context; this would be fine, except for your need to parameterize it.  If possible, change your code to run within a cfquery tag pair:

```
<cfquery...>
SELECT * FROM tableFoo
<cfif ListLen(arguments.uid_features)>
 WHERE uid_prodf_featid IN (<cfqueryparam value="#arguments.uid_features#" list="true" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">)
</cfif>
</cfquery>
```

Also, as you can see I've changed your query structure a bit - you had a lot of code to do something that is much more easily accomplished as I show above.

*edit*

I see that you actually are doing AND operations with each item in your uid_features list... I have a hard time imagining there being a valid logical reason for that (rather than OR), but if so, my example won't work for that - instead change it back to a series of AND conditions within the loop.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, however that's not what I'm trying to do. I am building a where statement from a list of id's which need to be added with an "AND" clause ie. 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 etc., I am then inserting the clause into into the query. like so  WHERE #featQuery# this builds the follow clause WHERE uid_prodf_featid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="5"> AND uid_prodf_featid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="6"> the in operator will give me to many results. I'm not great at explaining sorry!

Comment: Thanks, will try that now thank you. The AND operation is to drill to a particular set of products i.e products with slides and swings and monkey bars. not to get products with slides or swings etc.

Comment: Excellent using the loop worked perfectly thank you. I have put a tick in your answer as the edit you made was exactly what was needed!

Comment: I still don't see the logic in what you describe - WHERE uid_prodf_featid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="5"> AND uid_prodf_featid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="6"> will always return no results, since a single value cannot be simultaneously 5 and 6.  But anyhow - I'm glad you got something helpful out of this.

Comment: I bow down to your greater knowledge, you are correct! My problem is now greater then! My products have features assigned to them, I add the feature using a related table with the following structure. uid_prodfeat_feat, uid_prodfeat_featid(link to feature), uid_prodfeat_prodid(link to product). If a user clicks on monkey bars i display all the products with monkey bars, then if a user clicks swings i need it grab only products with swings and monkey bars. If i use the IN operator i get all products with monkey bars or with swings. Do i need to create a second query with the first query results